# Relative Position (to another object) in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I want an object to be placed 1 unit to the right with respect to another game object unit 3d, since the other game object have different orienetation and that messes up with the cordindate system. For example, when the object is facing North, right is x. But when the object is facing East, right is z. Is there a solution to this?

I tried

```
obj.transform.position +obj.transform.right*x
```

also tried `TransformDirection`. They did not work.

Comment: A bit unclear what you mean ... you **do** want it affected by the `obj`'s orientation or not? Could you show a complete code? What exactly does `did not work` mean? What is your expected outcome? What happened instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to be affected by orienetation, then just use the `Vector3.right` or `new Vector(1,0,0)` as the offset.

```
obj.transform.position + Vector3.right * x
```